# Boundary representation data structure for 3D library

Tags: haskell, data-structures, 3d, language-agnostic, geometry

I would like to implement an open-source Haskell library that would operate on geometric data, specifically [3D polygonal meshes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh), the way Blender, Maya, 3ds Max or Houdini do. The most important criteria is performance while modifying parts of those meshes, however I also want it to be able to represent objects composed of:

1. only vertices
2. polygons with any number of vertices
3. meshes with holes
4. (non obligatory) edges without polygons

and be able to assign to vertices, edges and polygons named properties. A named property is just an assotiation between a String and any type of data, like Int. This mirrors the way Houdini does it.

After reading about the different representations, it comes to mind that the
winged-edge or half-edge data structues are used in a multitude of libraries, but may be difficult or impossible to apply to objects like (1.), while searches for render dynamic meshes or the radial-edge data structure do not come up with clear explanations or actual implementations.

My question is what would be to best choice to represent these geo objects as described and why? And in case I need non 2-manifold representations, are there any implementations of radial-edge structures?

Comment: While this is a good question, I'd say that since you're asking for the "best choice to represent these geo objects", it's both too broad and too opinion based for this corner stackexchange.  This sort of problem also can't be answered in a few paragraphs, since anything that met 3 or 4 of your conditions would be necessarily lengthy.  I would recommend posting this to reddit.com/r/haskell and get some good discussion going to generate ideas on how to implement it. It's certainly an interesting problem (don't mistake my close vote for disinterest), it just doesn't fit the stackoverflow format.

Comment: The Haskell IRC might also be a good place to go to get advice like this.  There's usually some pretty experienced haskellers slacking off there too =P

Comment: @bheklilr: I do **not** agree with you. In my opinion this question is a precise question about a real problem. I'm also very interested in the answer. StackOverflow is a perfect place to have an answer, which shows possible pros and cons of solutions by listing them next to each other if is it possible. I strongly prefer to search for such topisc on SO, than just forget great answers (and IRC answers are going to /dev/null or are at least very hard to browse and search)

Comment: @bheklilr thanks for the advice, I re-posted this question on http://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/2a82m9/boundary_representation_data_structure_for_3d/ if anybody is interested

Comment: For many of the type of processing task a polygon mesh is used, having isolated points or edges makes no sense, while not-triangle polygons and holes are actually fine. So from a practical point of view, the half-edge or similar winged-edge structures are quite appropriate, and isolated points and edges might be handled as separate entities, not incorporated in your main data structure.

Comment: @WojciechDanilo this is about a specific problem, but the answer would be hugely complicated and is now if a general design question than a haskell one. It also isn't solving a specific problem that OP is stuck on, such as "I tried this data structure and it isn't working well, how do I do X with my data structure?". Again, I'm not saying it's a bad question to ask, I just personally think it has too broad of a scope to fit on SO.